# Xamarin Forms - Change the font size as per Device ie iPhone / iPad

Tags: ios, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

Hi does anyone know a way to change the font size based on the device that is displaying the @UI.

ie

```
// iPhone 5
if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height == 568)
    FontSize = 12
else 
     24pixles on IPad
```

I am using a Style Property.

But Large still looks tiny on the iPad

```
  <Style x:Key="lblDetailValueHighlighted" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
      <Setter.Value>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="NamedSize" iOS="Large" Android="Large" WinPhone="Medium" />

      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,1,3,3" />
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnIdiom`. For example:

```
<OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="StackOrientation">
    <OnIdiom.Phone>Vertical</OnIdiom.Phone>
    <OnIdiom.Tablet>Horizontal</OnIdiom.Tablet>
</OnIdiom>
```